# Problemas usando LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Intento traer una colección de datos usando LINQ to SQL pero cuando ejecuto la app me da error, estoy usando Visual Studio 2012 SQL Server 2008, app Windows Forms.

```
 private IEnumerable<Customers> ListarCustomers()
    {
        using (NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<Customers> custs = db.Customers.Where(x => x.City == "Rio de Janeiro")
                .Select(x => new Customers() {CustomerID = x.CustomerID, ContactName = x.ContactName, City = x.City});
            return custs.ToList();
        }
    }
```

El error es el siguiente:
No se permite la construcción explícita del tipo de entidad 'DemoDGV.Customers' en una consulta. DemoDGV es el nombre del proyecto.

También me sale el siguiente error
No se puede obtener acceso al objeto desechado.\r\nNombre del objeto: 'Se ha obtenido acceso a DataContext después de Dispose.'."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No entiendo por qué necesitas hacer:

```
.Select(x => new Customers() {CustomerID = x.CustomerID, ContactName = x.ContactName, City = x.City})
```

.. ya que el resultado del `Where()` ya es un enumerable de tipo `Customers`, y como puedes ver en el error que recibes, no le gusta que construyas una instancia de `Customers` en el `Select()`. Y se entiende, porque sino, le tocaría traducir esto en SQL, y no puede.

Deberías poder quitar el `Select()`, y debería funcionar correctamente:

```
private IEnumerable<Customers> ListarCustomers()
{
    using (NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext())
    {
        return db.Customers.Where(x => x.City == "Rio de Janeiro").ToList();
    }
}
```

**Edición**

Si el caso es que `db.Customers` no devuelve un set de tipo `DemoDGV.Customers`, y que tu intención es de convertir el resultado en una lista de `DemoDGV.Customers`, entonces la clave está en ejecutar el `ToList()` ***antes*** del `Select()`. De esta manera, el código no va a tratar de traducir el `Select()` en SQL, y debería funcionar correctamente.

Ejemplo:

```
private IEnumerable<Customers> ListarCustomers()
{
    using (NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext())
    {
        return db.Customers
               .Where(x => x.City == "Rio de Janeiro")
               .ToList()
               .Select(x => new Customers() {CustomerID = x.CustomerID, ContactName = x.ContactName, City = x.City});
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola le puse `.Select(x => new Customers() {CustomerID = x.CustomerID, ContactName = x.ContactName, City = x.City});` Quiero cargar esas columnas en un DGV

Comment: @Pedro: Osea que tienes 2 tipos diferentes que se llaman `Customers`? Cuales es el tipo de `db.Customers`?

Comment: es el único que trae el archivo .dbml, modifique la pregunta agregue otro error.

Comment: @Pedro: No entiendo tu respuesta.  Lo que quiero saber es si `db.Customers` devuelve un set de `DemoDGV.Customers` u otra cosa?

Comment: @Pedro: Modifiqué mi respuesta, esperando que entendí lo que estas tratando de hacer.

Comment: Funciono con la modificación que hicistes pero a que se debe, cuando he usado LINQ to Entities no me había dado problemas.